# Check for failed http requests in the TestCafe fixture

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, httprequest, testcafe

At times I encounter 500 and 502 errors when accessing parts of our application and we would like to be able to catch that error and fail the TestCafe test.

We currently have this setup https://stackoverflow.com/a/52443604/7551391 and it works fine when we call the `waitForFailedRequest` function and it's wrapped around the contents of the test but we would like to call it in the fixture or globally so that it will always look for 500, etc errors on each test.

My main question is what to use for the `action` param in `failed_requests.waitForFailedRequest()` so that it's called on every test.

**failed_request_hooks.js**

```
import EventEmitter from 'events'
import { RequestHook } from 'testcafe'


export class FailedRequestsLogger extends RequestHook {
    constructor (requestFilterRules, responseEventConfigureOpts) {
        super(requestFilterRules, responseEventConfigureOpts)

        this.events = new EventEmitter()
        this.failedRequestPromise = new Promise(resolve => this.events.once('failed-request', resolve))
    }

    async onRequest (event) {
    }

    async onResponse (event) {
        if (event.statusCode >= 500) {
            this.events.emit('failed-request', event.statusCode)
        }
    }

    async waitForFailedRequest (action) {                                                                                                          
        return Promise.race([                                                                                                                
                action(),                                                                                                                    
                this.failedRequestPromise.then(statusCode => Promise.reject(new Error(`Request failed with the ${statusCode} status code`))) 
        ])                                                                                                                
    }
}
```

**test_file**

```
import { ClientFunction, Selector } from 'testcafe'
import { FailedRequestsLogger } from '../../api/failed_request_hook'
import data from '../../data/data.json'
import EditUrlRedirectsObjects from '../../pom/sites/url_redirects/edit_redirects_page_repo'
import GooglePreviewPageObjects from '../../pom/sites/url_redirects/google_preview_page_repo'
import HelperObjects from '../../pom/helpers'
import LoginPageObjects from '../../pom/login/login_page_repo'
import SitesPageObjects from '../../pom/sites/sites_page_repo'
import URLRedirectsPageObjects from '../../pom/sites/url_redirects/url_redirects_page_repo'
import WorkspaceMainNavPageObjects from '../../pom/navigation/workspace_main_nav_page_repo'


const failed_requests = new FailedRequestsLogger(/.*reborncf\.com/)

fixture `sites - url redirects`
  .page `${HelperObjects.get_base_url()}`
  .requestHooks(failed_requests)
  .beforeEach(async t => {
    await LoginPageObjects.login_with_password()
    await failed_requests.waitForFailedRequest()
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to implement this in your use case. You can create [a request hook globally](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402638/reference/configuration-file#request-hooks) and use it as illustrated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52443604/7551391:

```js
//customRequestHook.js
const EventEmitter = require('events');
const { RequestHook } = require('testcafe');

class CustomRequestHook extends RequestHook {
    constructor (...args) {                                                                                                                  
        super(...args);                                                                                                                      

        this.events = new EventEmitter();                                                                                                    
        this.failedRequestPromise = new Promise(resolve => this.events.once('failed-request', resolve));                                     
    }                                                                                                                                        

    onRequest (request) {                                                                                                                    
    }                                                                                                                                        

    onResponse (response) {                                                                                                                  
        if (response.statusCode >= 500)                                                                                                      
            this.events.emit('failed-request', response.statusCode);                                                                         
    }                                                                                                                                        

    waitForFailedRequest (action) {                                                                                                          
        return Promise.race([                                                                                                                
                action(),                                                                                                                    
                this.failedRequestPromise.then(statusCode => Promise.reject(new Error(`Request failed with the ${statusCode} status code`))) 
        ])                                                                                                                                   
    }    
}

module.exports = new CustomRequestHook();
```

```js
//.testcafers.js
const customRequestHook = require('./customRequestHook.js');

module.exports = {
  hooks: {
    request: customRequestHook,
  },
};
```

```js
//test.js
import customRequestHook from './customRequestHook.js';

fixture`Fixture`
    .page('https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example/')
    .beforeEach(async t => {
        await customRequestHook.waitForFailedRequest(5000)
    });

test('Test', async t => {
    //test
});
```

If you don't want to cover your custom code, you can reorganize `waitForFailedRequest` and insert a timeout into it:

```js
//customRequestHook.js
const EventEmitter = require('events');
const { RequestHook } = require('testcafe');

class CustomRequestHook extends RequestHook {
    constructor (...args) {                                                                                                                  
        super(...args);                                                                                                                      

        this.events = new EventEmitter();                                                                                                    
        this.failedRequestPromise = new Promise(resolve => this.events.once('failed-request', resolve));                                     
    }                                                                                                                                        

    onRequest (request) {                                                                                                                    
    }                                                                                                                                        

    onResponse (response) {                                                                                                                  
        if (response.statusCode >= 500)                                                                                                      
            this.events.emit('failed-request', response.statusCode);                                                                         
    }                                                                                                                                        

    waitForFailedRequest(timeout) {
        return Promise.race([
            new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timeout)),
            this.failedRequestPromise.then(statusCode => Promise.reject(new Error(`Request failed with the ${statusCode} status code`)))
        ])
    } 
}

module.exports = new CustomRequestHook();
```

```js
//.testcafers.js
const customRequestHook = require('./customRequestHook.js');

module.exports = {
  hooks: {
    request: customRequestHook,
  },
};
```

```js
//test.js
import customRequestHook from './customRequestHook.js';

fixture`Fixture`
    .page('https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example/')
    .beforeEach(async t => {
        await customRequestHook.waitForFailedRequest(5000)
    });

test('Test', async t => {
    //test
});
```

Keep in mind that you can change the `waitForFailedRequest` method as you want because it isn't a `TestCafe` method. Only JS syntax limits you.

Comment: Can we set requestHooks globally in the .testcaferc file?

Comment: Thanks! Also, when throwing the error we are returned this in the spec report which is fine, but it doesn't appear to reject the promise as the test still continues to run.

`1) An unhandled error occurred in the "onResponse" method of the "FailedRequestsLogger" class:

      Error: Request failed with the 500 status code`

We want to be sure to reject the promise and stop the test (like when `skipJsErrors` is set to `true`) so that we aren't waiting for something on a page that will never show up since the page hit a 500.

Any help/refinements would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! I am using that code now but testcafe still appears to fail on the assertion timeout instead of the timeout that I give it (even when I set it to 2000ms).

Comment: You need to debug the `onResponse` method. Make sure that the response with code 500 appears before the timeout exceeds.

Comment: Is there any easy way to just spit out the 500 error in the reporter instead of failing the test?

Comment: You can use [`RequestLogger`](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402668/reference/test-api/requestlogger).